# What is the best tool to augment DOTA like custom dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, annotations, data-annotations, labelimg

My dataset is annotated using rotated bounding box annotation tool having (x1y1 x2y2 x3y3 x4y4 class category) is label format (same as DOTA).

My data directory contains:

1. images
2. train (txt labels)
3. val (txt labels)
4. test (txt labels)

I want to augment training folder along with annotations. What is the best tool/library that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `imgaug` library in Python.it is powerful library for image augmentation, including support for bounding box transformations.
documentation:https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am wonder it will work with DOTA like set or not? I am sure it is good for normal bbox like xywh but in my case it is xyxyxyxyclasscategory.